# If I expose an application on Kubernetes which have multiple replica with LoadBalancer, how could I know which pod is exposed?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I deploy Prometheus server with 2 replicas on AKS (Azure's kubernetes) with the following config.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  ...

spec:
  podMetadata:
  version: v2.13.1
  replicas: 2
  retention: 1d
  ...
```

So I will have 2 prometheus server pods on my cluster.
[image]

And then I expose this application with loadbalancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: prometheus
```

[image]

Everything work successfully here, however, how could I know which promethus pod is exposed by loadbalancer?
It seems only one prometheus pod is exposed by loadbalancer.

Comment: Why do you think only one prometheus pod is exposed by the loadbalancer? Your service should loadbalance the requests evenly between all your pods with the tag app=prometheus

Comment: What is the use case for running replicated Prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one replica of a pod all the pod replica's IPs are added as `Endpoints` to the service `prometheus`. So when traffic comes to the LoadBalancer it forwards it to the `prometheus` service IP which load balances the traffic and sends to one of the replica pods.

To check Endpoints of the service use below command

```
kubectl describe svc prometheus -n monitoring
```

If you see multiple IPs in the `Endpoints` section using  above command that essentially means that all those replica POD IPs are exposed by the service.